# Does superconductivity enable an analog to magnetic field flyback for the electric field?

Tags: superconductivity

Flyback being the act of rapid collapse of the magnetic field in a fractions of a second in order to abuse the law of induction $$L\frac{\mathrm di}{\mathrm dt}=V,$$
which occurs because resistance collapses the magnetic field faster. In the case of superconductivity, no resistance means basically an infinite magnetic field (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#:%7E:text=In%20electromagnetism%20and%20electronics%2C%20inductance,magnetic%20field%20around%20the%20conductor)).

However the inverse is true for capacitors. Their projection of the electric field & maintaining it for long periods of time is contingent on having a resistance (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current)).

With superconductors having no resistance, do superconductors enable a total collapse of the electric field in a fraction of a second & as a result dump all that energy into available receptacles?

Answer (score 0):

Superconductivity is not required. The analog of the voltage pulse produced by an inductor when you interrupt a circuit is the current pulse produced by a capacitor when you discharge it through low resistance.

Comment: I'm specifically thinking about a remote version having to do with the electric field, without a physical discharge path. For example: having the cathode capacitor plate suddenly not producing its half of the electric field(Thanos snapped it out of existence). Leaving the anode plate as having a huge positive charge & no negative field keeping the 'holes' in place. You'd have a lot of charge needing to move really quickly away from each other.(Qcharge/Time=Icurrent)